# Bootstrap Modal on BackboneJS view is not closing on background click or escape key

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I'm working with BackboneJS and Bootstrap to create a modal view. It is a details panel, rendered when a model view is clicked. I'm building it as follow:

ITEM VIEW:

```
myApp.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events : {
        'click' : 'itemClick',
    },

    itemClick: function(){
        this.detailsView.render(this.item);  
    },

})
```

MODAL VIEW:

```
DetailsPageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id:'myModal',

    initialize: function(){
        var self=this;
        _.templateSettings = {interpolate : /\{@=(.+?)@\}/g, evaluate : /\{@(.+?)@\}/g  };
        this.template = _.template($('#myModal').html());
    },

    render: function(item){
        this.$el.html(this.template({item: item}));
        this.item = item;
        this.setupItem(item);
        this.show();
        return this;
    },

    show: function() {
        this.$el.modal('show');
        return this;
    },

})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="true" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content antiAlias" style="width:800px;font-family:Arial,'Helvetica',sans-serif;">
      <div class="modal-header" style="border:0px;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div>{@= item.get('item_name') @}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

It is rendering as expected, with the default effects. And I can close it with the close button shown on html.

The problem is: I can't close the dialog by clicking ESC nor in the modal background. I've tried to bind the hidden.bs.modal event to call this.$el.modal('hide') but I'm not able to bind it in any way.

Thank you

Comment: Is the 'modal-open' class being placed on the body tag when the modal is open?

Comment: Hello Billy, it is not.. After rendering it if I execute $('.modal-open') on console I get []